# Is it ok to use test's sensitivity and specificity from other countries?

Tags: measurement, clinical-psychology, test

I want to calculate likelihood ratios of test scores in clinical psychological assessment setting. In my country, validation studies for many common used tests are missing or information about sensitivity and specificity of test values are missing for certain populations.

My question is: Is it valid for me (in Czech Republic) to use information about sensitivity and specificity of the test for example from Germany or UK validation studies?

Thanks

Comment: Voted to close as being too broad; there are many tests and some may be standardized and some not. It may be institution and even lab-dependent